# unable to close output pane in pgadmin4

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

How to close the pgamin output window.. I dragged/popped out the output window of pgadmin 4 .. and now I can't close it/merge it back on the top tile.
Restarting application doesn't work. looks like it remembers my last action(s)

Also, I see a blank window. 
I am using pgadmin4

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured out- 
Choose below from the tool bar: 
File -> RestLayout

[image]

Answer (score 0):

And now I can prevent accidentally opening more windows with *File* > *Lock Layout* > *Prevent Docking*:

[image: Prevent Docking Menu]